# What are the different way to make deep copy of object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on ReactJS project where I'm having problem with copying an Object and I've got one solution to use `structuredClone` but is there any other ways to do it?

I just want different solutions of this problem of my react project.